When was the first Shabbas observed?
When did God introduce the concept of resting on the seventh day? Specifically , did the Avos know about it ?

Didn't He do it already the first week? Genesis 2:2-3

According to the Midrash, Adam composed Mizmor Shir LeYom HaShabbat.

as @DoubleAA highlights, this question is rather open ended. I suspect you have more specific intentions than the way you worded it so I recommend editing in more detail and clarity

As to the question of whether the Avot kept mitzvot, see the extensive discussion at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot

Bereshis Rabbah 16 says Adam was taught about Shabbos on the very first week:

וַיַּנִּחֵהוּ, נָתַן לוֹ מִצְוַת שַׁבָּת, כְּמָה דְאַתְּ אָמַר (שמות
כ, יא): וַיָּנַח בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי. לְעָבְדָהּ, (שמות כ, ט):
שֵׁשֶׁת יָמִים תַּעֲבֹד. וּלְשָׁמְרָהּ, (דברים ה, יב): שָׁמוֹר אֶת
יוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת לְקַדְּשׁוֹ.‏
“Vayaniḥehu” – He gave him the mitzva of Shabbat, just as it says:
“And He rested [vayanaḥ] on the seventh day” (Exodus 20:11). “To
cultivate it [le’ovda]” – “six days you shall work [taavod]”
(Exodus 20:9), “and to keep it” – “Keep the Shabbat day” (Deuteronomy
5:12). (“To cultivate it and to keep it” all refer to the precept of
Shabbat – to work for six days and rest on the seventh.)


See Did Adam celebrate the first Shabbat in Gan Eden https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88146/did-adam-celebrate-the-first-shabbat-in-gan-eden which discusses whether Adam HaRishon spent the first Shabbat in Gan Eden

@EdwardB Where Adam spent the first Shabbat, is irrelevant to the discussion.

Would you say that this Midrash holds that keeping Shabbos was incumbent upon Noahides? This is quite a new concept to me.

@IsraelReader I wouldn't say that. Maybe it was incumbent on Adam, but until Sinai Judaism was more of a lifestyle than a set of commandments. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67945/6592.

Until Sinai, there were the Noahide commandments, which actually started with Adam (6 to Adam +1 to Noah). But we're seeing a new commandment here, Shabbos. You're going to have make a big stretch here, saying that Shabbos was only incumbent on Adam, while the other commandments were mandatory to his progeny too. Is that your intent?

@IsraelReader Not necessarily, but I don't see it as such a stretch either. Were his progeny commanded not to eat from the tree?
